# Hashtable "default" getter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-2.0

A particular class has a Hashtable containing 1..N elements.  I'm wondering if there are generic getter/setter methods for the Hashtable used in a class.  I'm looking to make the hashtable values behave more like regular object properties:

```
public class foo 
{
  private HashTable _stuff;
  public HashTable stuff { get; set; }
  public foo() {}
}
```

I was wondering if something like this can happen:

```
foo bar = new foo();
bar.stuff.name; //returns the data in the 'name' index if it exists
bar.stuff.name = "Me"; //sets the stuff[name] value = "me"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like that in the current version of C#.  The dynamic stuff in C# 4.0 will make this easier.

In the meantime, why not just make Name (and other values) simple properties?  While you're at it, you'll find the generic `Dictionary<K,V>` easier to work with than `HashTable`.

Comment: The elements in the Hash are coming from a database query.  The keys in the hash == db columns from the query.  We were hoping that a change to the stored procedure would change a dynamically generated HTML table/list on the front end without a bunch of extra coding to account for the added field.

Comment: For that, a standard table/dictionary seems like the easiest way to go.  For each key in the table, add a column to the generated HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with C#, at least not in the current version.  What you'd need is the equivalent of method_missing in ruby.

If this was C# 4.0 you could do something similar to this with anonymous types and the dynamic keyword, however you'd need to know the keys up front.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can do that in .NET 4.0 by implementing the [IDynamicMetaObjectProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider(VS.100).aspx) interface... doesn't seem trivial though !

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are rendering the HTML there might be a few ways to solve your problem.
The code above is as noted not possible at current in c#.

First of all I assume there's a reason why you don't use ADO objects, that usually solve the rendering problems you mention (together with `GridView` or similar).

If you want to generate a class with "dynamic" properties you can create a [`propertybag`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/propertybag.aspx)

it will not make the above code possible though but will work with a rendering engine based on `TypeDescriptor` using custom descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) in c# 4.